# How can I find all nodes around a point that are members of a way with a certain tag?

Tags: overpass-api

I would like to find all highway way member nodes in a certain radius.  I cannot see how to do this without using intersection, however, that is not in the API.  For example I have this:

```
[out:json];
way(around:25, 50.61193,-4.68711)["highway"];>->.a; 
(node(around:25, 50.61193,-4.68711) - .a);
out;
```

Result set `.a` contains the nodes I want but also nodes outside the radius - potentially a large number if the ways are long.  I can find all the nodes inside the radius I don't need, as returned by the complete query above.  Now I can always perform a second `around` query and do the intersection of the two result sets outside of Overpass.  Or I can do another difference:

```
[out:json];
way(around:25, 50.61193,-4.68711)["highway"];>->.a; 
(node(around:25, 50.61193,-4.68711) - .a)->.b;
(node(around:25, 50.61193,-4.68711) - .b);
out;
```

This gives the result I want but can it be simplified? I'm certain I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, your query can be simplified to an extent that we don't need any difference operator at all. I would recommend the following approach:

- We first query for all nodes around a certain lat/lon position and a given radius.
- Based on this set of nodes we determine all ways, which contain some of the previously found nodes (-> Hint: that's why we don't need any kind of intersection or difference!).
- Using our set of highway ways we now look again for all nodes of those ways within a certain radius of our lat/lon position.

In Overpass QL this reads like:

```
[out:json];
node(around:25, 50.61193,-4.68711);
way(bn)[highway];
node(w)(around:25, 50.61193,-4.68711);
out;
```

Try it on [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/5qU)

Comment: Thanks that is interesting, I was not aware filters could be combined in that way.